# How to access to a store into array of stores? Using Svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I'm using [svelte-forms](https://chainlist.github.io/svelte-forms/) and need to make an array of [fields](https://chainlist.github.io/svelte-forms/#field)

> field() returns a writable store and is a convenient function to create a new form input that will serve a your input controller.

Suppose the next scenario

```
<script lang="ts">
    let fields = [field("f1","f1",[]), field("f2","f1",[]);
</script>

{#each fields as field}
   {$field}
{/each}
```

How can i use the fields array to access to any field store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new top level scope by extracting the content of the each to a separate component. That way accessing the store will work as expected. E.g.

```html
{#each fields as field}
   <Sub {field} />
{/each}
```

```html
<!-- Sub.svelte -->
<script>
    export let field;
</script>

<input bind:value={$field.value} />
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/ee9984b3bf284bc8ada03b2cca4f4483?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Why the `field` store is not accessible in the parent component? why I need another sub component to use any field?

Comment: @AngelPonce A current limitation of Svelte, it will tell you something to that effect in the error message. Stores need to be declared at the top level to be accessed via `$` syntax. (You can still access them in other ways.)